# 2sxc Permissions by Role

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

Using 2sxc 8.8 for DNN Evoq Content 8.3, is it possible to setup a role that will allow a user to see the buttons, edit and change template / layout, but does not allow them to "Edit Template" and give them "Admin" access?

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple to do, because once a special user-group exists called "2sxc Designers", only these users will see the advanced buttons.

Check out http://swisschecklist.com/en/fwttmwjx/2sxc-Hide-advanced-features-from-Content-Editors-with-Designer-Security-Role

Comment: I created the role "2sxc Designers" in Evoq 08.03.00. The advanced features are hidden from the 2sxc Editors; however when I assigned the role to an "Admin" the features were still hidden. Is this a bug (using 2sxc version 8.8.0)? @iJungleBoy

Comment: This would not be a known bug. As soon as as the group exists, only these group members see the advanced buttons.