# How to Configure Permissions in 2sxc News App

Tags: permissions, dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I'm using the 2sxc News App for DNN and I'm trying to figure out how to grant users the ability to add/edit/delete news posts without also granting them the ability to change the layout or edit the module.

I tried to add the "2sxc Designers" role [I've read about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41228428/2sxc-permissions-by-role):

[image: added group]

But having that role doesn't seem to change anything.

**Am I doing something wrong in setting the "2sxc Designers" role and is this what I need to allow only post manipulation?**

Comment: Note 1: The 2sxc Designers role is for the web-designers (html pros etc.), not for the content editors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an advanced use case, and I can't give you the full answer, but basically what you want to do is this:

1. On the content-type, give the group custom permissions - so that the UI accepts changes by them https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/wiki/concept-permissions
2. Since the toolbars won't appear for non-editors, you'll have to make this happen in the template. So add some razor to check if people of this role. Then enable edit with Edit.Enable https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/wiki/razor-edit.enable

These blog-posts may also help you: https://2sxc.org/en/blog/post/recipe-create-public-forms-with-2sxc